# Why does this script not work if the file has a .py extension?

Tags: python-2.7, coinbase-api

I'm following the instructions in the Coinbase API guide [Coinbase Guide](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/guides/send-receive) The first line of the code is to simply load the Coinbase library:

```
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client
```

I'm using IDLE as the IDE. If I work on a file with no extension (e.g. simply called 'coinbase') then the examples in the guide work fine.

If I work on a file with the standard Python extension (e.g. 'coinbase.py') it does not load the Coinbase library and errors out! The error message is:

```
ImportError: No module named wallet.client
```

I think this may not necessarily Coinbase related, and perhaps I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. Answers appreciated.

Comment: Is the python file in the same directory of the code files? otherwise you need to navigate to that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that all python files are seen by python as modules.
So when you write a script called coinbase.py, python will see it as a module and let you import it with `import coinbase`. Doing so you are shadowing the *real* `coinbase` module that you meant to import, hence the error.

To fix the problem simply avoid calling your files with existing module names (unless of course you intend to shadow them).

Comment: Ahh I see, so calling my file the same as the module (Coinbase and coinbase) has led to confusing Python. Great thanks a lot